# PHP-cURL Adding entry to an array in a function not working

Tags: php, arrays, function, curl

I can echo the response i get just fine in the function request_callback so I thought it trivial to just save the response into an array associative_array[], however this yields just single entries, like the array gets wiped after every entry.

I make use of https://github.com/LionsAd/rolling-curl/blob/master/RollingCurl.php

```
<?php
# Get the all the items numbers
$url1 = "http://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings";
$response1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$data1 = json_decode($response1, true);

#retrieve item names and link with numbers
function request_callback($response) {
    $temporary_array = json_decode($response, true);
    $associative_array[] = array('name' => $temporary_array['name'],'id' => $temporary_array['id']);
    // array[] places the new entry at end of urls stack, faster then array_push($array, new entry);
    print_r ($associative_array);
    echo "\n";
}

# Multiple curl request
require("rollingcurl.php");

for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++){   
        $itemurl1 = "http://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/{$data1[$x]}";
        $urls[$x]= $itemurl1;  
    }   
$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
$rc->window_size = 20;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
     $request = new  RollingCurlRequest ( $url ) ;
     $rc -> add ( $request ) ;
}
$rc->execute();


?>
```

Comment: Where does `$urls` come from? Can you post a `var_dump` of it?

Comment: beginner mistake to try and download all the data in parallel. respect the servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is local to your function, hence reseting on each call.
Try adding global declaration and you will get what you expect (all values);

```
function request_callback($response) {
    global $associative_array;
    $temporary_array = json_decode($response, true);
    $associative_array[] = array('name' => $temporary_array['name'],'id' => $temporary_array['id']);
    // array[] places the new entry at end of urls stack, faster then array_push($array, new entry);
    print_r ($associative_array);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you now the array entries get added! But I think I read while searching that global is bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create your array outside of your function. It looks like you're creating a new array on every function call.

```
$associative_array = array();
function request_callback($response) {
        global $associative_array;
        $temporary_array = json_decode($response, true);
        $associative_array[] = array('name' => $temporary_array['name'],'id' => $temporary_array['id']);
        // array[] places the new entry at end of urls stack, faster then array_push($array, new entry);
        print_r ($associative_array);
        echo "\n";
}
```